# Does Mkdocs need to be installed for maintaining a mkdocs-based Read-the-Docs project?

Tags: read-the-docs

I installed MkDocs, created a local project, and uploaded it to GitHub. Then, in Read-the-Docs, I created a project linked to the Github repo set to auto build. The output looks as expected and updates as expected when I make changes to the files in Github.

Now, I am a bit confused about the role of MkDocs going forward. As far as I can tell, it is not really needed any more by either me or anyone else who wants to contribute...we just need to edit/create markdown and image files in the github repo as needed and Read-the-Docs takes care of the rest? The only reason I can think to have MkDocs installed is if I (or someone else working on the project) wants to run a local MkDocs server to see how edits get rendered locally before adding them to github. Is this right or am I missing something?

(Having MkDocs installed is clearly not a problem...I just want to know what is going on. Please be as patronizing as you like in your reply...I am a tech writer, not a developer :-)  )

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, "it is not really needed"? Do you mean as a requirement in your pip requirements? Locally, yes, you need to install it. RTD will install MkDocs as a requirement if you specify it as the build target.

Comment: A colleague who does not have MkDocs installed edited the related project in github as a collaborator and those edits appeared in the RTD output. I suppose similarly, if I were to uninstall MkDocs and then do the same thing as my colleague my edits would also appear. Isn't this indicating that MkDocs is no longer needed?

Comment: If you want to build the docs on your local development machines (not RTD), then you need to install MkDocs there. In general, it is a good idea to test the build of your docs locally or as part of your automated testing, before you accept edits that immediately get deployed to a production environment.

Comment: Thanks Steve, that is exactly what I wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have installed MkDocs locally unless you want to build your project's documentation locally. Read the Docs installs all the dependencies specified in the `.readthedocs.yaml` config file (see https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#python).

However, even if there is no config file specifying the dependencies (e.g. MkDocs) to build the documentation, Read the Docs will install some mandatory dependencies to build your documentation (e.g. MkDocs or Sphinx). This is why when a collaborator edits a file on GitHub, without anything installed locally, reflects the changes properly on Read the Docs.